# Get long live Facebook picture URL

Tags: profile, facebook-unity-sdk

I am implementing leaderboards so, my first approach was when the user first logs in his display name and picture url is saved on playfab so in my code I first get the leaderboards then download the image and display well this would take much time already until now I got that the url is not long enough and leaderboard did not work properly

What would be the best and valid approach for this?
btw I am using unity.

I have tried using the **redirect=true** pram but no luck.

Comment: How big is the picture to take too much time to download?

Comment: only the small profile pic but since we are talking about leaderboards there is not only one but nearly hundred and specially if their are more than that players it wolud be that every 100 player has its own leaderboards, you see that?

Comment: Yes but you don't need to load everything at once load it sequentially one by one using coroutine without blocking the main thread that way the game stay smooth

Comment: I am loading through coroutines but you have not understanded the question quitely, see loading too much images will lead to bigger load times like first downloading the leaderboards then downloading the url of each player then the whole image for that unlike other games load the leaderboard instantaneously while if I get the answer to my question it would slow the user load time dramatically.